# Find the larger array

Tags: javascript

I am looking to see if one array has a single larger value than the next and returning `true` if a larger array is found. What is wrong with my code? I'm testing it with these two arrays: `[1,2,3,4]` and `[1,2,3,3]`.

```
function isFirstSuperior(arr1, arr2) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr2.length; i += 1) {
    if (arr1[i] > arr2[i]) {
      return true
    } else {
      return false
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this only checks first value in array then exits the function

Comment: Cannot understand your problem.Can you be more precise?

Answer (score 1):

Don't return false in the `else` statement. Remove the else, and add a `return false` **after** the for loop.

```js
var array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var array2 = [1, 2, 3, 3];
function compareArrays(arr1, arr2) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr2.length; i += 1) {
    if (arr1[i] > arr2[i]){
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
console.log(compareArrays(array1, array2));
```

**EDIT:** With slightly more modern JS syntax, you can use `array.some()` instead.

```js
var array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var array2 = [1, 2, 3, 3];
function compareArrays(arr1, arr2) {
    return arr1.some((cur, index) => cur > arr2[index]);
}
console.log(compareArrays(array1, array2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Math.max() here (see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max)

```js
const array1 = [1,2,3,4];
const array2 = [1,2,3,3];
function compareArrays() {
  if (Math.max(...array1) > Math.max(...array2)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

The above function returns `true` if the max value of `array1` is > the max value of `array2` (as in the question)

Comment: This world work, but OP seems to be trying to check for if values of the same index are larger, not if the maximum of an array is larger.

Comment: @Lemondoge it's unclear for sure. I think you are right that that is what their code is trying to do, but I read the text of the question to mean that they want to compare the entirety of the array

Comment: You don't really need an if-else statement here. Just return the comparison immediately.